# Bootstrap Icon peeking out behind sticky element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Bootstrap Icon appears to work fine when not behind a sticky element.[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpLX8.png)

I have a table which has a set of columns which contain data in textual and link formats. The Bootstrap icon as displayed in the image tend to peek out when they slide behind a sticky element. the first 2 columns in this table are the sticky elements. I have tried setting up z-index values , but that did not seem to work. Here is a function that does the formatting for the link based text.

```
function format() {
            $("#showData tr td").each(function () {
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((www|http|https|ftp|pdf):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a href="$1" target="_blank"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Download </a>'));
            });
            $(function () {
                $('#showData tr a[href$=".pdf"]').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Download PDF');
            });
            $(function () {
                $('#showData tr a[href$="&outputformat=shape-zip"]').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>Download Shapefile');
            });
        }
```

Comment: Add complete code in code plunker or something like that, then we can understand what exactly you want.

Comment: Without further context, I would say look into z-index css property for the icons.